# Oboe stops rendering audio if there is too many data to be rendered

Tags: android, c++, audio, oboe

I'm trying to implement Oboe library into my application, so I can perform low latency audio playing. I could perform panning, playback manipulation, sound scaling, etc. I've been asking few questions about this topic because I'm completely new to audio worlds.

Now I can perform basic things which internal Android audio class such as `SoundPool` provides. I can play multiple sounds simultaneously without noticeable delays.

But now I encountered another problem. So I made very simple application for example; There is button in screen and if user taps this screen, it plays simple piano sound. However fast user taps this button, it must be able to mix those same piano sounds just like what `SoundPool` does.

My codes can do this very well, until I taps button too much times, so there are many audio *queues* to be mixed.

```cpp
class OggPlayer;

class PlayerQueue {
private:
    OggPlayer* player;

    void renderStereo(float* audioData, int32_t numFrames);
    void renderMono(float* audioData, int32_t numFrames);
public:
    int offset = 0;
    float pan;
    float pitch;
    int playScale;

    bool queueEnded = false;

    PlayerQueue(float pan, float pitch, int playScale, OggPlayer* player) {
        this->pan = pan;
        this->playScale = playScale;
        this->player = player;
        this->pitch = pitch;

        if(this->pan < -1.0)
            this->pan = -1.0;
        else if(this->pan > 1.0)
            this->pan = 1.0;
    }

    void renderAudio(float* audioData, int32_t numFrames, bool isStreamStereo);
};

class OggPlayer {
private:
    std::vector<PlayerQueue> queues = std::vector<PlayerQueue>();
public:

    int offset = 0;
    bool isStereo;
    float defaultPitch = 1.0;

    OggPlayer(std::vector<float> data, bool isStereo, int fileSampleRate, int deviceSampleRate) {
        this->data = data;
        this->isStereo = isStereo;
        defaultPitch = (float) (fileSampleRate) / (float) (deviceSampleRate);
    }

    void renderAudio(float* audioData, int32_t numFrames, bool reset, bool isStreamStereo);
    static void smoothAudio(float* audioData, int32_t numFrames, bool isStreamStereo);

    void addQueue(float pan, float pitch, int playerScale) {
        queues.push_back(PlayerQueue(pan, defaultPitch * pitch, playerScale, this));
    };

    static void resetAudioData(float* audioData, int32_t numFrames, bool isStreamStereo);

    std::vector<float> data;
};
```

`OggPlayer` holds decoded PCM data with `defulatPitch` value to sync speaker's sample rate and audio file's sample rate. Each `OggPlayer` holds its own PCM data (meaning each audio file's data), and it holds its own vector of `PlayerQueue`. `PlayerQueue` is the class which actually renders audio data. `OggPlayer` is PCM data provider for `PlayerQueue` classes. `PlayerQueue` has its own custom pitch, pan, and audio scale value. Since `AudioStream` can provide limited size of array in callback methods, I added `offset`, so `PlayerQueue` can continue rendering audio in next session without losing its status.

```cpp
void OggPlayer::renderAudio(float *audioData, int32_t numFrames, bool reset, bool isStreamStereo) {
    if(reset) {
        resetAudioData(audioData, numFrames, isStreamStereo);
    }

    for(auto & queue : queues) {
        if(!queue.queueEnded) {
            queue.renderAudio(audioData, numFrames, isStreamStereo);
        }
    }

    smoothAudio(audioData, numFrames, isStreamStereo);

    queues.erase(std::remove_if(queues.begin(), queues.end(),
            [](const PlayerQueue& p) {return p.queueEnded;}), queues.end());
}
```

This is how I render audio data currently, I seek through each `OggPlayer`'s `PlayerQueue` vector, and make them render audio data by passing pointer of array if they didn't reach end of PCM data array yet. I smooth audio data after finishing audio data, to prevent clipping or other things. Then finally remove queues from vector if they finished rendering audio (completely).

```cpp
void PlayerQueue::renderAudio(float * audioData, int32_t numFrames, bool isStreamStereo) {
    if(isStreamStereo) {
        renderStereo(audioData, numFrames);
    } else {
        renderMono(audioData, numFrames);
    }
}

void PlayerQueue::renderStereo(float *audioData, int32_t numFrames) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        if(player->isStereo) {
            if((int) ((float) (offset + i) * pitch) * 2 + 1 < player->data.size()) {
                float left = player->data.at((int)((float) (offset + i) * pitch) * 2);
                float right = player->data.at((int)((float) (offset + i) * pitch)  * 2 + 1);

                if(pan < 0) {
                    audioData[i * 2] += (left + right * (float) sin(abs(pan) * M_PI / 2.0)) * (float) playScale;
                    audioData[i * 2 + 1] += right * (float) cos(abs(pan) * M_PI / 2.0) * (float) playScale;
                } else {
                    audioData[i * 2] += left * (float) cos(pan * M_PI / 2.0) * (float) playScale;
                    audioData[i * 2 + 1] += (right + left * (float) sin(pan * M_PI / 2.0)) * (float) playScale;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if((int) ((float) (offset + i) * pitch) < player->data.size()) {
                float sample = player->data.at((int) ((float) (offset + i) * pitch));

                if(pan < 0) {
                    audioData[i * 2] += sample * (1 + (float) sin(abs(pan) * M_PI / 2.0)) * (float) playScale;
                    audioData[i * 2 + 1] += sample * (float) cos(abs(pan) * M_PI / 2.0) * (float) playScale;
                } else {
                    audioData[i * 2] += sample * (float) cos(pan * M_PI / 2.0) * (float) playScale;
                    audioData[i * 2 + 1] += sample * (1 + (float) sin(pan * M_PI / 2.0)) * (float) playScale;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    offset += numFrames;

    if((float) offset * pitch >= player->data.size()) {
        offset = 0;
        queueEnded = true;
    }
}

void PlayerQueue::renderMono(float *audioData, int32_t numFrames) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        if(player->isStereo) {
            if((int) ((float) (offset + i) * pitch) * 2 + 1 < player->data.size()) {
                audioData[i] += (player->data.at((int) ((float) (offset + i) * pitch) * 2) + player->data.at((int) ((float) (offset + i) * pitch) * 2 + 1)) / 2 * (float) playScale;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if((int) ((float) (offset + i) * pitch) < player->data.size()) {
                audioData[i] += player->data.at((int) ((float) (offset + i) * pitch)) * (float) playScale;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(audioData[i] > 1.0)
            audioData[i] = 1.0;
        else if(audioData[i] < -1.0)
            audioData[i] = -1.0;
    }

    offset += numFrames;

    if((float) offset * pitch >= player->data.size()) {
        queueEnded = true;
        offset = 0;
    }
}
```

I render everything (panning, playback, scaling) queue has in one session, considering both speaker and audio file's status (mono or stereo)

```cpp
using namespace oboe;

class OggPianoEngine : public AudioStreamCallback {
public:
    void initialize();
    void start(bool isStereo);
    void closeStream();
    void reopenStream();
    void release();

    bool isStreamOpened = false;
    bool isStreamStereo;

    int deviceSampleRate = 0;

    DataCallbackResult
    onAudioReady(AudioStream *audioStream, void *audioData, int32_t numFrames) override;
    void onErrorAfterClose(AudioStream *audioStream, Result result) override ;

    AudioStream* stream;
    std::vector<OggPlayer>* players;

    int addPlayer(std::vector<float> data, bool isStereo, int sampleRate) const;

    void addQueue(int id, float pan, float pitch, int playerScale) const;
};
```

and then finally in `OggPianoEngine`, I put vector of `OggPlayer`, so my app can hold multiple sounds in memory, making users able to add sounds, and also able to play them in anywhere, anytime.

```cpp
DataCallbackResult
OggPianoEngine::onAudioReady(AudioStream *audioStream, void *audioData, int32_t numFrames) {
    for(int i = 0; i < players->size(); i++) {
        players->at(i).renderAudio(static_cast<float*>(audioData), numFrames, i == 0, audioStream->getChannelCount() != 1);
    }

    return DataCallbackResult::Continue;
}
```

Rendering audio in engine is quite simple, as you may expect, I just seek through vector of `OggPlayer`, and call `renderAudio` method. Below code is how I initialize `AudioStream`.

```cpp
void OggPianoEngine::start(bool isStereo) {
    AudioStreamBuilder builder;

    builder.setFormat(AudioFormat::Float);
    builder.setDirection(Direction::Output);
    builder.setChannelCount(isStereo ? ChannelCount::Stereo : ChannelCount::Mono);
    builder.setPerformanceMode(PerformanceMode::LowLatency);
    builder.setSharingMode(SharingMode::Exclusive);

    builder.setCallback(this);

    builder.openStream(&stream);

    stream->setBufferSizeInFrames(stream->getFramesPerBurst() * 2);

    stream->requestStart();

    deviceSampleRate = stream->getSampleRate();

    isStreamOpened = true;
    isStreamStereo = isStereo;
}
```

Since I watched basic video guide of Oboe like [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_duWv9IPNvx9YBudNMmLSa) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vOf_fDtur4), so I tried to configure basic settings for LowLatency mode (for example, setting setting buffer size to burst size multiplying 2). But audio starts to stop rendering when there are too many queues. At first, sound starts to stutter. It feels like it skipping some of rendering session, and then it completely stops rendering if I tap playing button more after this. It starts to render again after I wait for a while (5~10 seconds, enough time to wait for queues to be emptied). So I have several questions

1. Does Oboe stop rendering audio if it takes too much time to render audio like situation above?
2. Did I reach limit of rendering audio, meaning that only limiting number of queues is the solution? or are there any ways to reach better performance?

These codes are in my flutter plugin, so you can get full codes from this [github](https://github.com/MandarinSmell/FlutterOggPiano/tree/master/android/src/main/cpp) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Oboe stop rendering audio if it takes too much time to render audio like situation above?

Yes. If you block `onAudioReady` for longer than the time represented by `numFrames` you will get an audio glitch. I bet if you ran `systrace.py --time=5 -o trace.html -a your.app.packagename audio sched freq` you'd see that you're spending too much time inside that method.

> Did I reach limit of rendering audio, meaning that only limiting number of queues is the solution? or are there any ways to reach better performance?

Looks like it. The problem is you're trying to do too much work inside the audio callback. Things I'd try immediately:

- Different compiler optimisation: try `-O2`, `-O3` and `-Ofast`
- Profile the code inside the callback - identify where you're spending most time.
- It looks like you're making a lot of calls to `sin` and `cos`. There may be faster versions of these functions.

I spoke about some of these debugging/optimisation techniques [in this talk](https://youtu.be/tWBojmBpS74?t=1526)

One other quick tip. Try to avoid raw pointers unless you really have no choice. For example `AudioStream* stream;` would be better as `std::shared_ptr<AudioStream>` and `std::vector<OggPlayer>* players;` can be refactored to `std::vector<OggPlayer> players;`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, and rich tips! I will try to optimize my codes more, thanks a lot again